# Advanced Search in List Views in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, list-view

I am new to lightning.

I understand adding custom views and adding specific set filters to it. But is there a way to setup soft-filters like this?

> Show all records in `<California, New York, Texas>` that expire between `<Today>` and `<07/04/2019>` and containing the word `<Magic>`

I mean, the filter values should not be set. Instead, the user should be able to pick the state from a multi-picklist and specify a date range etc.

This seems so basic for any list view, but I can't seem to figure it out. None of my google searches are returning good results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to create custom facet with a range slider, you might want to share the code you have attempted so far in order to get help from the community.

Otherwise, I know you can search for a managed package that includes out of the box functionalities for faceted search components [here](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SalesforceV2/Getting+Started+with+Coveo+for+Salesforce+Express) . The free version doesn't support the date range facet at the moment, however you can narrow down search results by adding facets related to available fields you have in your objects (for example, show records from California, New York, Texas) which originate from a multi-value pick list.

The Enterprise version does support range facets with dates as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried anything custom yet because I assumed this was too basic for it to not exist. Did not want to reinvent the wheel. So before I get started with my own facet with range filter, can I pass the user selected value to the default/native lightning list view and have it display the results accordingly? I don't want to recreate the actual data table, mass edit, etc which are already available oob. Just want to throw in custom filter components on the top and have them talk to native list view.